# Is music good for plants?

Tags: plant-health

I was watching a documentary on plants, and I came across this section that tells about the effect of music on plants. It says that Rock music kills plants while some other type of music encourages growth. One such music was composed by Roger Roger named "Rhapsody in Green."

Are these plants music really helpful to plants? If yes, how often do I make them listen, and for how long?

Here is the documentary:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-4w5xYLwiU

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Rhapsody in Green by Roger Roger was a spoof album, part classical, part electronic, produced decades ago. If it was that good at keeping plants happy, I'm pretty sure we'd all have heard about it by now - play them some Mozart instead of heavy rock music, that's said to be beneficial to both plants and humans, though my plants are just fine and they have to put up with electronic and rock music quite frequently.

Comment: Hi 4-K! It's probably just my confusion, but I don't understand this question. What is Rhapsody in Green by Roger Roger? Would you mind explaining something about that, and maybe changing the title a bit so that when we come across the question it's more obvious what you mean? I thought it was the name of a plant! Most of what I Google is coming up in French. Thanks!

Comment: For the moment, I'm going to vote to close as unclear what you're asking. As you know, other people would have to agree before it would get closed, and you can still edit it.

Comment: I think it is an interesting question, but I'm not sure whether it fits better here or on [Biology SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one [goes back a ways](http://www.theosophy-nw.org/theosnw/brother/br-jvmj2.htm):

> In the early 1950s Dr. T. C. Singh, head botanist of the Annamalai University, India, discovered that the hydrilla, a water plant, reacted to Indian ragas played on violin, flute, and vina. Further experiments with various pitches of sound caused certain plants greatly to increase their yields.

[In the 1970's](https://dengarden.com/gardening/the-effect-of-music-on-plant-growth), Country music was found to have no effect on plant growth, Jazz is beneficial, and Rock will kill your plants. One of the researchers,  Dorothy Retallack, even wrote a popular book on the subject: [The Sound of Music and Plants](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL5430692M/The_sound_of_music_and_plants) (1973).

Music does jiggle air around, but as far as I know, no mechanism of action has ever been tested, nor have there been any large scale trials. I'd think that, if music worked, people would know about it, and use it.

Answer (score 3):

No.

As far as I know, plants have no ears, or any other audio organ to "hear" or "listen" music. Many plants, of course, can be physically impacted by the vibration of sound and plants in general, do respond to external forces, such as gravity (geotropism), or your pruner. But sound, even those "better" sound (music)? It's almost nothing when compared with even the lightest wind or drizzle.

If the " documentary" states that "Rock music kills plants while some other type of music encourages growth," Then there should be publication(s) documenting such astounding breakthrough and would have attracted a heckuva lot of attention. No, never heard of it, or just me living under a rock?

Comment: Really the organ to hear, is not very different to our: hairs. Just they don't have a "real brain", so probably they listen every frequency separately, so not much different on different type of music.